# Remove CSS & JS from <?php wp_head(); ?>

Tags: css, javascript, wp-head

I've been with this problem for a couple of days and the truth is that I can not find a solution. I have added code manually in wp-header.php and now I need to delete these lines that it generates automatically

The lines I want to eliminate are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="create-css" href="http://www.myweb.com/wp-content/themes/movil/create.css?ver=4.9.8" type="text/css" media="all" data-inprogress="">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myweb.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myweb.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>
```

thaks!!

Comment: What code did you ad manually? You shouldn't add scripts and styles to the header manually.

Comment: We are trying to pass the web from http to https, but we do not know why those three codes are not edited and they always remain in http giving errors on the page.

Comment: What we have done is add those same three codes but with https manually and now we want to eliminate those that generates <?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: you should remove what you have added manually and add https in the site url and home page url in settings.

Comment: The whole web is already working in https, we have added the url in the configuration of the site, but those three codes are not edited and we do not know why it happens. That is why we have decided to add it manually in the wp-head.php and try to eliminate it from the <?php wp_head(); ?>

Comment: The only thing we want to know is how we can remove those three codes from <? Php wp_head (); ?>

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some filter is placing the create.css file there. Check your functions.php (or search for the following function inside the theme with your text editor in case some other file is enqueueing those assets) for `wp_enqueue_style` and see if you have that file enqueued.

Other way of doing this is using the filter `wp_head`, so, you might have something like this in your functions.php or maybe elsewhere in your theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_callback_function');

my_callback_function() { ?>
       <link rel="stylesheet" id="create-css" href="http://www.myweb.com/wp-content/themes/movil/create.css?ver=4.9.8" type="text/css" media="all" data-inprogress="">
<?php
}
```

If you want to delete the code above you can, but instead of manually placing the tag, you should use something like the code below, again, in your functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_callback_function');

function my_callback_function() {
    wp_enqueue_style('create-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/create.css');
}
```

The script tags you are seeing in your website normally come from the WordPress core, so you won't have to delete them, placing them again, or do anything, WordPress handles that for you and it will use http or https depending on your configuration.

The possibility exists that someone overwrote the enqueueing of the scripts (if http doesn't change automatically to https when you configure https in your website, then something is not right) to use something different to what the WordPress core gives you, in which case you should search and see if somewhere in your theme the filter `wp_head` or the function `wp_enqueue_script` is being used to put those files there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should backup your site first.  Then go in to the editor under appearance, and find the file your looking for.  Its usually under appearance on the dashboard.

Appearance > Editor

Then you can delete the files in question.

If they are styles and scripts, deleting them may break certain functions, or make your site look odd.

If you are hosting the stylesheets and scripts on your website, and you have converted all other links on the website, you should probably just add an "s" into the http:// protocol, changing it to https://

Comment: Hi. First thank you try to help us. I followed your instructions but we could not eliminate those three codes. Inside WP-Head.php we find the code <? php wp_head ();?> which is the one that general those three codes that we want to eliminate.

Comment: It would not be possible to eliminate them by adding some code like this in the fuctions.php ??remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  It sounds like it may be a dependency of a certain plugin or possibly your theme itself.  because wp_head pulls in a variety of things.  I think you should try a plugin that tries to force https on all links, or test deactivating plugins/ themes until you find what is passing in the unsecure links.  Then you could either leave it disabled or try editing it.  It might be easier/safer to migrate the whole site to a local server to test configuration changes.